# How to replace array.join using a comma with using a line break

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, ecmascript-6

I am using rest parameters ... to collect all keys in an array.

For mapping the wanted keys, you could join all wanted property values.
using

```js
function getValues(array, ...keys) {
  return array.map(object => keys.map(key => object[key]).join(', '));
}

var jobs = [{
  startDate: "5/2017",
  endDate: null,
  isCurrent: true,
  seniority: "Senior"
}, {
  startDate: "5/2013",
  endDate: "5/2019",
  isCurrent: false,
  seniority: "Junior"
}];
```

However, I want to add a line break after every iteration

**Additional Info**
I'm calling the function in a react and material-ui component as follows

```
{getValues(jobs, 'seniority', 'startDate')?
   <TableCell>
      {getValues(jobs, 'seniority', 'startDate')}
    </TableCell> :
   <TableCell style={{backgroundColor:'#FFC7CE',color:'#9C0006'}}>
     [MISSING] 
   </TableCell> 
}
```

But The data gets joined up

Comment: instead of , change it to \n. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

Then change the separator from a comma `,` to a line break `\n`. Then iterate through the array and log each line.

```js
function getValues(array, ...keys) {
  return array.map(object => keys.map(key => object[key]).join('\n'));
}

var jobs = [{
  startDate: "5/2017",
  endDate: null,
  isCurrent: true,
  seniority: "Senior"
}, {
  startDate: "5/2013",
  endDate: "5/2019",
  isCurrent: false,
  seniority: "Junior"
}];

getValues(jobs, 'seniority', 'startDate').forEach(e => console.log(e));
```